# How to solve rigid body dynamics with rotation (impuls & energy equations)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When describing rigid body dynamics during collision, one can make use of impulse and energy equations to describe the velocities of both objects after the collision. Below are 2 equations, with 2 unknowns ($v_{1,new}$ and $v_{2,new}$), which can thus be solved.

[image]

In case of an added rotational degree of freedom, two additional degrees of freedom emerge ($\omega_{1,new}$ and $\omega_{2,new}$). However, I still have only 2 equations below, and thus I don't know how to solve this.

[image]

Which two equations am I missing to solve the problem?
Or is there another approach to this problem?

Comment: conservation of angular momentum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at this example:

[image]
a ball hit the rod at the distance of $~L~$ from the center of mass. we want to obtain the velocity $~v_M~$ and the angular velocity  $~\omega_M~$ of the rod after elastic collision.

**Step I**

write the equation of motions at the collision time .

$$m\,\frac{dv_m}{dt}=-F_c\\
M\,\frac{dv_M}{dt}=F_c\\
I\,\frac{d\omega}{dt}=F_c\,L$$

where $~F_c~$ is the constraint force

**Step II**

integrate the equation of motions:

$$m\,\int _{u}^{v_m}dv_m=-\int F_c\,dt=-dp\\
M\,\int _{0}^{v_M}dv_M=\int F_c\,dt=dp\\
I\,\int _{0}^{\omega_M}\,d\omega=\int F_c\,dt\,L=dp\,L$$

from here

$$m\,(v_m-u)=-dp\\
M\,v_M=dp\\
I\,\omega_M=dp\,L$$
you have now 3 equations for 4 unknows $~v_m~,v_M~,\omega_M~\,dp~$

the forth equation that you need  is the conservation of the energy

$$\frac 12 m\,v_m^2+\frac 12 M\,v_M^2+\frac 12 I\,\omega_M^2=
\frac 12 m\,u^2$$

Notice that only  the linear momentum

$$m\,v_m+M\,v_m=m\,u$$

is conserved.

---

**Results**

with $~I=M\,r^2~$

$$v_M=2\,{\frac {m{r}^{2}u}{m{r}^{2}+m{L}^{2}+M{r}^{2}}}\\
\omega_M=2\,{\frac {mu}{L \left( 2\,m+M \right) }}$$

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation. As far as I know,  if the surfaces of the objects are smooth, and if they are spheres, the rotation of one body doesn't affect the other. So, the equations will remain the same.